# Haskell find value of converging sequence

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

Brand new to Haskell. I'm playing around with fibonacci sequence to learn the basics of the language and I can't find the idiomatic way to do something.

The Fibonacci sequence can be defined like this:

```
fibs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

(That's already pretty cool). Then, I want to use the sequence to approximate the Golden ratio (Phi). So :

```
ratios = zipWith (/) (tail fibs) fibs
```

is a list of better and better approximations of Phi. Let's say I want to get the first value when the list has "stabilized" under a given threshold epsilon. (ie: the difference between two successive values of ratios is smaller that epsilon). I can see how I would do that in an imperative language (using indexes), but how would one do that idiomaticly in Haskell?

(Do we need to use the following list ? But how ?)

```
diffs = zipWith (-) ratios (tail ratios)
```

Comment: Hint: `zip ratios diffs` will be a list of `(ratio, derivative)` pairs. So you'll wanna [find the first element](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:dropWhile) in `zip ratios diffs` for which the derivative is below the threshold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How? By using another `zip`. Here is a one-liner based on what you already have:

```
snd . head . dropWhile (\(p1,p0) -> abs (p0 - p1) >= epsilon) $ zip ratio (tail ratio)
```

Reading from right to left, this says:

- `zip` together the list of ratios with their successors
- from the list continue dropping elements if the difference between the ratios is greater than `epsilon`
- once that is done, we take the first element of the list and pick the more precise of the two.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility would be to use [list comprehensions](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension):

```
getApprox threshold = head $ [ratio | (ratio, diff) <- zip (tail ratios) diffs
                                    , abs diff < threshold
                             ]
```